# How to save vim registers in evil mode for use after restarting emacs

Tags: evil

In evil mode, I can save text in named registers with `"ay` etc. These registers are lost whenever emacs is restarted. Is there a way to save these registers? Vim seems to do this automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways of persisting data in Emacs, such as using desktop.el or savehist. If you have enabled `savehist-mode` in your init file (like by adding `(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'savehist-mode)`), it's a matter of defining one extra variable to save:

```
(setq savehist-additional-variables '(register-alist))
```